# Appending hexlifyed content to file

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
file_1 = ('test.png')
with open(file_1, 'rb') as b:
    file_hex = b.read()    
binascii.hexlify(file_hex)
file_1_size = len(file_hex)
print (file_1_size)

file_new = open("test.tp", "a")
file_new.write(binascii.hexlify(file_hex))
file_new.close()
```

I've been trying to get this hexlifyed content appended to the file. I've even tried to apply the hexlifyed content to a variable of its own. like this,

```
file_1 = ('test.png')
with open(file_1, 'rb') as b:
    file_hex = b.read()    
x = binascii.hexlify(file_hex)
file_1_size = len(file_hex)
print (file_1_size)

file_new = open("test.tp", "a")
file_new.write(x)
file_new.close()
```

both end with error

```
TypeError: must be str, not bytes
```

Comment: awesome thank you, i figured it was just being stupid and missing something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your file in binary mode to append bytes:

```
with open("test.tp", "ab") as file_new:
    file_new.write(x)
```

or decode your bytes to a string first:

```
with open("test.tp", "a") as file_new:
    file_new.write(x.decode('ascii')
```

Hex digits fall within the ASCII code range, so decoding with that codec is safe.